# shift when using coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

There is something I don't quite understand about coordinates, but I'm pretty sure you will be able to explain

This is an example of the problem

```
\documentclass[tikz, border = 3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
  \coordinate (B) at (4, 4);
  \draw (A) rectangle (B);

  \fill[red, xshift = 20pt] (B) circle (0.3) node[above = 7pt]{doesn't work};
  \fill[blue, xshift = 20pt] (0, 0) circle (0.3) node[below = 7pt]{works};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem is when I try to use `shift` with a previously defined coordinate, e.g.

```
\fill[red, xshift = 20pt] (B) circle (0.3);
```

As shown in the picture, it clearly doesn't shift the circle. Why is that?

Thanks in advanve

Comment: The transformations are only applied if a coordinate is parsed. Named shapes have already fixed locations on the canvas and they are just "looked up". That's why generic transformations don't affect them.

Comment: @percusse Thanks for the comment, what is then the most versatile way of parsing the coordinate? I tried something like  `($ (B) $)` but the result is the same

Comment: Parsing in this context means TikZ seeing a `(` and then discovers numbers or dimensions in it. If it sees a name it directly looks up the coords. sergiokapone's answer is one way or you can use `(B)++(20pt,0)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be worked with coordinate assigned to letter if you apply shift option near coordinate letter `\fill[red] ([xshift=20pt]B) circle (0.3) node[above = 7pt]{doesn't work};` but not for path.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border = 3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
  \coordinate (B) at (4, 4);
  \draw (A) rectangle (B);

  \fill[red] ([xshift=20pt]B) circle (0.3) node[above = 7pt]{doesn't work};
  \fill[blue, xshift = 20pt] (0, 0) circle (0.3) node[below = 7pt]{works};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I see, thanks. Is this the only way? Becase a `scope` doesn't solve either